# How to remove displaying client name in Auth0 classic login?

Tags: authentication, auth0

I am using Auth0 client login in one of my applications. There is a requirement for me to remove the client name from appearing on the hosted ui. Does anyone know how to do this? In the below image, the "iOs Demo App 1" is the name of the application which I don't want to display.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for the answer please refer to the [Lock UI Customization docs](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/lock-ui-customization#customizing-text)

```
var options = {
  languageDictionary: {
    emailInputPlaceholder: "something@youremail.com",
    title: "Log me in"
  },
};
```

By changing the title of this language dictionary will change the text on the login page